# Line numbers and text files Java

Tags: java

I'm studying for my finals and i wondering if there is a particular way of printing out the  data of a line in a text file. for example if i had the following in a text file:

```
11 
1c20 
203 
G2
```

I was wondering if there is a way where I input for example 2 ,4 i would get an output 1c20 203 G2. by using two integers start and finish. i have research for this method, but unable to find anything. I understand there is a  is a getLineNumber() but i want to use the two Integers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be very easy with sed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option (with pointers):

1. [Read the inputs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and store them in a two variables `start` and `end`
2. Read each line using [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), increase the counter for each line
3. If the line number is in the range, print the line.
4. When counter reaches `end`, break from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at java.io.LineNumberReader: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html

Note that line numbers start at 0

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;

/*
 * Usage: java LinePrinter <start> <end>
 * Example: java LinePrinter 2 4
 */
public class LinePrinter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int end = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        LineNumberReader reader = null;
        String line = null;
        boolean flag = false;

        try
        {
            reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (reader.getLineNumber() == start)
                {
                    flag = true;
                }

                if (flag)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                if (reader.getLineNumber() == end)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've looked at this, and i don't find it Convenient

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is named data.txt, you can use sed to display lines 3 thru 5 like this:

$>     sed -n '3,5p' data.txt

Comment: can you expand please and yes my text is called java.txt thanks

Comment: The above is an example of how to use the sed command to do what you want: print lines x thru y of a file.  The command is named sed.  The -n means quiet mode.  The 3 represents the starting line.  The 5 represents the end line.  The comma separates the start and end lines.  The p represents the desired operation, in this case print.

Comment: In order to use the sed command, you have to have to be using linux, unix, or Mac.  If you're on silly windows, you have to install Cygwin to escape your otherwise useless environment.

Comment: Then you would have to install Cygwin to use the sed command.  It's not that hard to install and it's very handy.  I recommend it highly.  Once installed, you can use the above command to print lines x thru y of a file from the command line.